# Перевод числа из шестнадцатеричной системы в двоичную

Tags: алгоритм, c++, системы-счисления

Самая банальная ситуация, встречается чрезвычайно часто, но у меня с ней проблема.
Суть такова, нужно `HEX` перевести в `BIN`, для этого и функция есть, `HexToBin`, но никак не могу реализовать, на форумах пишут что неудобная.
И все это нужно записать в текстовый файл, с этими функциями еще не сталкивался.

Буду признателен за краткий пример использования `HexToBin`, С++.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду? Создать символьную (`char *`) строку из нулей и единиц?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Convert strings between hex format and binary format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18310952/4279)

Answer (score 5):

*Поскольку вы в тэгах написали `C++`, то отвечу в стиле именно `C++`, а не, например, `C`.*

Стандартный способ решения перевода `X->binary` и наоборот - это использование `std::bitset`.

**Вот пример использования:**

```
const std::string string("0x31c3");

std::istringstream stream(string);
int i;
stream >> std::hex >> i;

std::cout << '"' << string << "\": " << i << "(0x" << std::hex << i << ")\n";
std::bitset<16> bitset = i;

// 'to_string' вернет строку std::string формата '000...0111'
std::cout << "Binary : " << bitset.to_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вывод символов (цифр) числа в нужной системе счисления (в Вашем случае 2) состоит в циклическом вычислении остатков от деления числа на основание системы счисления (именно их надо выводить (в обратном порядке)) с последующим делением числа на основание. Цикл продолжается, пока число больше нуля. Для отрицательных модификация очевидна.

Для Вашего случая и (допустим это максимум) 64-разрядных целых достаточно буфера 66 символов (с учетом знака и ограничителя строки). Заполняйте его справа налево, а потом скопируйте все, что навыводили к началу. Вместо деления можно использовать сдвиг вправо (x >> 1), а вместо вычисления остатка проверку младшего бита (x & 1).

Answer (score 1):

Очень полезно задачу осмыслить. И понять что должно быть на входе и выходе. Еще становится ясно, что можно задачу разбить на два этапа:
 1. Получение из строки числа в hex-виде и приведение его к "человеческому виду"
 2. Преобразование в строковый вариант бинарного представления.

Для п.1 я могу предложить использование вполне стандартной ф-ции strtol. Ее прелесть в том, что она сама умеет отрезать 0x и она умеет из строки число выдирать в любой системе счисления. Функции sscanf, scanf, fscanf тоже умеют на входе воспринимать 16-ричное число как строку и правильно сохранять значение в переменную ти int. Ну, или можно воспользоваться методом с потоками с++. Делайте так как Вам понятнее.

Для преобразования в бинарный вид тоже можно задействовать ф-ции Си. ltoa и ltostr подойдут. Иначе придется вручную высчитывать остатки от деления на два и добавлять к строчке их в правильном порядке.

Вероятно, что проще чем так мучаться, воспользоваться простейшей идеей - между шестнадцатеричной и двоичной записью числа есть простое соответствие. Каждой hex-цифре соответствует определенная четверка битов. Т.е. можно даже тупо составить таблицк вида 0-0000, 1-0001....a-1010..f-1111. И можно просто заменой символа на подстроку нахаляву преобразовать вид записи числа.

Answer (score 1):

Каждая шестнадцатеричная цифра переходит ровно в 4 двоичных цифры:  A<sub>16</sub> = 1010<sub>2</sub>.

Поэтому легко написать код, который превратит произвольно большую hex-строку в "01"-строчку—для каждой hex-цифры добавляем соответствующие биты в результат:

```c++
#include <string>
#include "hex2bin_table.h"

/// hex: "A" -> "1010", else: "\n" -> "\n"
std::string hex2bin(const std::string& hex)
{
  std::string bits;
  for (unsigned char hex_digit : hex)
    bits += hex2bin_table[hex_digit];
  return bits;
}
```

Чтобы избежать многократных выделений памяти при росте `bits` строки, можно добавить перед циклом: `bits.reserve(4 * hex.size())`. Но следует измерить производительность, чтобы понять какой эффект это имеет в вашем случае.

Пример:

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string hex = "CAFEBABE\n8BADF00D\nDEADBEEF\nD15EA5E";
  std::cout << hex2bin(hex) << std::endl;
}
```

#### Результат

```c++
11001010111111101011101010111110
10001011101011011111000000001101
11011110101011011011111011101111
1101000101011110101001011110
```

Для проверки можно обратно биты в шестнадцатеричные цифры превратить, к примеру на Питоне:

```py
>>> 0b11001010111111101011101010111110 .to_bytes(4, 'big').hex()
'cafebabe'
```

`hex2bin_table`—это таблица hex -> bin, в которой для каждой hex-цифры записаны соответствующие битовые строки:

```c++
const char* const hex2bin_table[] = {
"\x00", "\x01", "\x02", "\x03", "\x04", "\x05", "\x06", "\x07", 
...
"\x28", "\x29", "\x2A", "\x2B", "\x2C", "\x2D", "\x2E", "\x2F", 
"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", 
"1000", "1001", "\x3A", "\x3B", "\x3C", "\x3D", "\x3E", "\x3F", 
...
};
```

Позиция строки определяется ASCII кодом для соответствующей hex-цифры: `'A' ==  65`, поэтому `hex2bin_table['A'] == hex2bin_table[65] == "1010"`. Байты, которые не соответствуют шестнадцатеричным ASCII цифрам представляют сами себя в виде С строки: `hex2bin_table[0x2e] == "\x2e"`.

Таблицу можно сгенерировать автоматически, к примеру на Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from string import hexdigits

print('const char* const hex2bin_table[] = {')
for char in map(chr, range(0x100)):
    if char in hexdigits: # interpret as hex-digit and print as bits
        print('"{:04b}",'.format(int(char, 16)))
    else: # as itself
        print(r'"\x{:02X}",'.format(ord(char)))
print('};')
```

или вместо таблицы [можно использовать функцию с простым `switch(hex_digit)` ветвлением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311086/4279).