# Python как написать функцию перевода из k-ичной системы в десятичную?

Tags: python

Python как написать функцию перевода из k-ичной системы в десятичную?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Элементарно, используя стандартную функцию int()

```
numberstr='22h'
print (int(numberstr, 30))
```

Единственное ограничение: основание может быть от 2 до 36. Если нужна другая база, надо писать самому. Это другой разговор.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что int в CPython не хранится в десятичной системе (`sys.int_info`). `print` вызывает `str(int)` функцию, которая и преобразует int в строку, содержащую десятичные цифры (это не бесплатная операция—[она может занимать долгое время для больших чисел](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что в таком мощном Пайтоне, всё таки есть нужная функция. Полистайте мануал. Если что, смотрите в преобразования методом Горнера. Вот JS, надеюсь вы сможете перевести её в Python:

```
function 2dec ( str, base ) {
        base = (!base)? 2:Number(base);
        str = str.split('');
        var s = 0; 
        for( var k in str ) {

            s = (base*s + (str[k]-0));
        }
    return s;
    }
```

Comment: А как самого себя минуснуть?

Comment: js: `parseInt('12h', 36)`

Comment: @istem, зачем? Посетители сами упорядочат ответы голосами.

Answer (score 0):

Решение для основания `36` с помощью `reduce` (python2):

```
str = '1zz';
res=reduce(lambda x,y:x*36+('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.find(y)), str.strip().upper(),0)
print res; # 2591
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` в CPython не хранится в десятичной системе:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.int_info
sys.int_info(bits_per_digit=30, sizeof_digit=4)
```

`print(some_number)` вызывает `str(int)` функцию, которая и преобразует `int` в строку, содержащую десятичные цифры (это не бесплатная операция—[она может занимать долгое время для больших чисел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279)).

Будем считать, что задача в вопросе: преобразовать строку `kstr`, содержащую натуральное число в `к`-ичной системе исчисления в Python `int` объект.

Если нельзя использовать `int(kstr, base)` напрямую (основание больше 36, цифры нестандартные, то легко в цикле собрать из отдельных цифр соответствующее число. К примеру, аналог 100<sub>3</sub> = 9<sub>10</sub>:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda n, d: n * 3 + d, map("012".index, "100"))
9
>>> int("100", 3)
9
```

Если цифры `abc`, а не `012` то есть для baa<sub>3</sub> = 9<sub>10</sub>:

```
>>> reduce(lambda n, d: n * 3 + d, map("abc".index, "baa"))
9
```

Вот более подробно о том [как reduce() функция последовательность цифр
в число превращает (для основания 10)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603463/23044).

Можно написать функцию, которая автоматически генерирует функцию преобразования (converter) по заданным цифрам системы счисления:

```
from functools import reduce

def make_converter_int_from_base_k(digits):
    """Return int(kstr, len(digits)) analog for any digits."""
    if not digits:
        raise ValueError('no digits')
    k = len(digits)
    basek2digit = {d:i for i, d in enumerate(digits)}.__getitem__
    def converter(kstr):
        if not (set(kstr) <= set(digits)) or not kstr:
            raise ValueError('invalid literal for int with digits {digits!r}: {kstr!r}')
        return reduce(lambda number, digit: number*k + digit, map(basek2digit, kstr))
    return converter
```

Пример:

```
>>> base3 = make_converter_int_from_base_k('abc')
>>> base3('c')
2
>>> base3('ba')
3
>>> base3('baa')
9
```

[Пример из Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) как число, представляющее `Man` в ASCII, можно в основание 64 преобразовать (5071214<sub>10</sub> = 4d616e<sub>16</sub> = TWFu<sub>64</sub>):

```
>>> import base64
>>> import string
>>> int.from_bytes(b'Man', 'big')
5071214
>>> base64.b64encode(b'Man')
b'TWFu'
>>> base64digits = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + '+/'
>>> base64decode = make_converter_int_from_base_k(base64digits)
>>> base64decode('TWFu').to_bytes(3, 'big')
b'Man'
```

Если известны ограничения на вводимые числа, то можно попробовать [угадать систему счисления по самому числу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/362356/23044), не задавая `digits` явно.

При преобразовании между некоторыми парами систем исчисления, иногда
достаточно только строковых замен без промежуточного
преобразования в int. К примеру из 16-ной в 2-ную
([hex2bin()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595577/23044)), из 2-ной в
8-ную ([bin2oct()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598823/23044)).

Стоит заметить, что int в CPython не хранится в десятичной системе (`sys.int_info`). `print` вызывает `str(int)` функцию, которая и преобразует `int` в строку, содержащую десятичные цифры (это не бесплатная операция—[она может занимать долгое время для больших чисел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279)).

Answer (score 0):

Вот функция из любой системы в десятичную, работает с любыми числами:

```
def fromAny(x, y):
    b = []
    for j in x:
        if j in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
            b.append(int(j))
        else:
            k = ord('A') + ord(j) - 120
            b.append(k)
    b.reverse()
    a = 0
    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        a += b[i] * (y**i)
    return a
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).