# Программа, угадывающая систему счисления по строковой записи числа

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Подскажите алгоритм угадывания. Есть программа, определяющая минимальную систему, а нужна, которая угадывает, т.е. дает приблизительный ответ и может ошибаться.

**Обновление**

http://ideone.com/xu8Rwh - вот программа, что есть. Сейчас она переделана под рандом в неком промежутке, но требуется нечто похожее, только без ранд()....

**Обновление**
системы счисления от 2-й по 36-ую.... т.е. и "экзотические" тоже.

Comment: @drian007, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: к закрывающим - и переоткрывающим - за что закрыли этот вопрос? на него дано несколько отличных обоснованных ответов, да и сама по себе задача из вопроса имеет вполне конкетное решение.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете только приблизительно предположить систему счисления из общеизвестных, на основе их общих признаков. Угадать программа не сможет, так как это вопрос чистого восприятия, а именно: все позиционные системы с более высоким основанием включают в себя системы с основанием ниже. Однозначное ограничение лишь в одном, это какую алфавитную мощность имеет число.

---

В программе стоит опираться на метод наименьшей возможной, а именно:

- Двоичная: если встречаются только 0 и 1, то это возможно она и ниже не идем. Есть не удовлетворяющий символ? Ищем его в системе с основанием выше.
- Восьмеричная: символы от 0 до 7. Есть не удовлетворяющий? Идем выше.
- Десятичная: символы от 0 до 9. Есть не удовлетворяющий? Идем в основание выше.
- Шестнадцатиричная: символы ABCDEF? Определенно шестнадцатиричное. Есть другой символ? Говорим, что данная система нам не известна.
- и т.д.

В итоге такой метод проваливания на основе признаков - это единственный вариант. А так число "07" для меня может быть как восьмеричное, так и десятиричное, шестнадцатиричное и даже двоичное {0,7}, троичное {0,7,X} или любое другое, какое мне вздумается. Правда, не меньше двоичной, из-за мощности алфавита в два символа.

Comment: "символы от 0 до 10" - это неплохо.

Comment: @BuilderC, всякое случается, поправил))

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что можно с достаточно большой вероятностью определить в общем случае.  Может, есть какие-нибудь ограничивающие условия?

Если на вход идет строка: `10`. То тут никак не определишь. Ну а если частично, то можно проверять символы `ABCDEF` в тексте, тогда это точно шестнадцатеричное число. Для двоичного, если есть дополнительные нули в тексте, например, `0001`. Но опять же в зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: >можно проверять символы ABCDEF в тексте, тогда это точно шестнадцатеричное число

Не все так однозначно. В вопросе нигде не говорится, что система не может быть, к примеру, семнадцатеричной. Да, такие системы счисления - это экзотика, и вряд ли где-то применяются всерьез, однако, еще раз повторю, в вопросе не указано, что подобные системы не рассматриваются.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что любая строка, которую можно рассматривать как число в `n`-й cистеме счисления, будет также числом в `(n+1)`-ой, `(n+2)`-ой и т.д. систем счисления.

Поэтому задачу сводится к тому чтобы найти минимальное такое `n`.

Если нет ограничений на цифры, например, если `ab` может рассматриваться как число в двоичной (2-ой) системе счисления, то ответ это *количество уникальных символов во входной строке*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
s = input("Введите число:") # " VIiI"
base = len(set(s.casefold().strip())) # "viii" -> 2
print("База минимальной системы счисления для {}: {}".format(s, base))
```

Программа предполагает, что пробелы до и после числа не считаются за цифры.

Если за цифры считать только символы воспринимаемые людьми ([Unicode grapheme clusters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)), то можно использовать `\X` регулярное выражение:

```
import regex # $ pip install regex
# ...
base = len(set(regex.findall(r"\X", s.casefold().strip())))
```

Если ввести дополнительное ограничение, что цифры должны быть стандартными, например, только `0123456789abcdef` цифры разрешены для шестнадцатиричной (16-ой) системы, не считая регистра букв, тогда *системы счисления от 2-й по 36-ую можно определить по самой старшей цифре во входной строке*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
s = input("Введите число:") # " numbEr"
rank = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".find
base = max(map(rank, s.casefold())) + 1 # 31
if not base:
   sys.exit("Не получилось найти систему счисления для {!r}".format(s))
print("База минимальной системы счисления для {}: {}".format(s, base))
```