# Как реализовать перевод систем счисления с дробной частью в python?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию, которая будет переводить из двоичной системы исчисления в восьмеричную числа с дробной частью (2.5, например)?

Comment: тут есть хорошее описание http://planetcalc.ru/862/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цифры числа в двоичной системе являются множителями перед соответствующими степенями двойки в зависимости от позиции. К примеру: 10.1<sub>2</sub> == 1⋅2<sup>1</sup> + 0⋅2<sup>0</sup> + 1⋅2<sup>-1</sup>. Цифры в дробной части стоят перед отрицательными степенями.

В восьмеричной системе основой является 8, то есть 2<sup>3</sup>. Поэтому каждые три бита соответствуют одной восьмеричной цифре. К примеру:  010<sub>2</sub> == 2<sub>8</sub>, 100<sub>2</sub> == 4<sub>8</sub>.

Для удобства конвертирования, дробную часть можно нулями дополнить, чтобы длина стала кратна трём: 10.1<sub>2</sub> == 10.100<sub>2</sub> == 2.4<sub>8</sub>. В Питоне 3:

```
from math import ceil

def bin2oct_float(bits):
    n, dot, f = bits.partition('.')
    return bin2oct(n) + dot + bin2oct(f.ljust(3 * ceil(len(f) / 3), '0'))
```

где `bin2oct(bits)` умеет "01"-строки преобразовывать (`set("01").issuperset(bits)`):

```
def bin2oct(bits):
    return bits and '{:o}'.format(int(bits, 2))
```

Пример:

```
>>> bin2oct_float('10.1')
'2.4'
```

Можно не преобразовывать в `int`, а только над строками операции производить:

```
def bin2oct(bits, bits2digit={'{:03b}'.format(i): str(i) for i in range(8)}):
    bits = bits.zfill(3 * ceil(len(bits) / 3))
    return ''.join([bits2digit[bits[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(bits), 3)])
```

Код использует [идиому по обходу последовательности ровно `n` элементов за раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434328/4279). Код не поддерживает знаки, пробелы во вводе: `'+1.111'`, `'- 1.0'`.

При переносе кода на язык без встроенных словарей, можно использовать аналоги вложенных списков, чтобы по трём битам выбрать восьмеричную цифру:

```
def bits2digit(a, b, c):
    return [['01','23'], ['45','67']][a][b][c]
```

Пример:

```
>>> bits2digit(1, 0, 0)
'4'
```