# Объединение элементов списка: из цифр сделать целое число

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список `gen = [1,2,3,4]`
Необходимо объединить элементы в число, чтобы получилось `1234`.
У меня получилось так:

```py
chislo = int(''.join((str(i) for i in gen)))
```

Нет ли способа проще, без преобразования типов?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Convert list of ints to one number?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/489999/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489999/convert-list-of-ints-to-one-number

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы последовательность цифр в число превратить:

```
digits = [1, 2, 3, 4]
number = int(''.join(map(str, digits)))  # -> 1234
```

Это близко к коду в вопросе и преобразует все цифры в строки, объединяет их в одну строку, которая преобразуется в целое число. [Это уродливый (из-за преобразований туда-сюда: `int<->str`), но более быстрый способ для тысяч цифр по сравнению с `reduce()` решением ниже.](https://gist.github.com/zed/ac0f5df365dffdb94f97476a89d38c8f#file-summary-org)

Можно обойтись без преобразований типа:

```
from functools import reduce 

number = reduce(lambda n, d: 10*n + d, digits)
```

где вместо [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) можно явно цикл написать:

```
number = digits[0]
for d in digits[1:]:
    number = 10 * number + d
```

Можно [посмотреть  визуализацию  промежуточных шагов,  как number считается, на pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=digits%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203,%204%5D%0Anumber%20%3D%20digits%5B0%5D%0Afor%20d%20in%20digits%5B1%3A%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20number%20%3D%2010%20*%20number%20%2B%20d&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):

```
number = 1
number = 10 * 1 + 2 = 12
number = 10 * 12 + 3 = 123
number = 10 * 123 + 4 = 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = len(gen) - 1
res = 0
for i, v in enumerate(gen):
    res += v * 10 ** (x - i)
```

Чуть красивее решение:

```
gen = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum([value * 10 ** index for index, value in enumerate(gen[::-1])])
```

Comment: Черт, кто говорил-то, что массив символьный ) +1

Comment: @slippyk круто :) и быстро

Comment: @slippyk и как всегда - минимум слов и хороший код.

Comment: вместо `sum([..])` можно писать просто `sum(..)`, не создавая промежуточный список: `sum(digit * 10**place for place, digit in enumerate(digits[::-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = filter(str.isdigit, repr(gen))
num = int(s)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/2Ktqd1)

Comment: у вас здесь разве не преобразование типа? num = int(s)

Comment: @dio4, вроде того. Но на мой взгляд - это более удачный код для Вашего задания. Но это на мой взгляд, как Вам - ... ))

Comment: Это не мое задание и мне ваш ответ понравился ))  но там есть таки преобразование типов, а автор просит без оного ;)

Comment: @dio4, сейчас будет.

Comment: @dio4, или не будет ))) Я подумал, что можно перебрать это в цикле, домножая на 10, но там тоже нужно делать преобразование.

Comment: сам мучаюсь.. )))  но ты молодец, ответ классный был(хоть и преобразование было)

Comment: @dio4, спасибо ))

Comment: @dio4: это напоминает ["Yo-Yo code"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/260710/1985), который следует избегать.

Comment: Кому и что это напоминает - дело сугубо индивидуальное, согласитесь. А значит, это глубоко субъективно. Я вас уважаю, глядя на ваши ответы этого форума, но это не означает, что вы истина в первой инстанции. Сколько людей, столько и мнений, согласитесь. А что надо избегать, а чего придерживаться - это вопрос очень риторический. Код должен быть простым и ясным, а не таким, как "вам" нравится :) Конечно, с Керниганом или Торвальдсом я бы не стал спорить, но вы, согласитесь, еще далеко не они(если я не путаю ничего..).

Comment: два слова еще..мне нравится slippyk во всех отношениях. Никакого менторства в "голосе", никакого "поучительства", самолюбования,  минимум слов, а если и исправит кого где, то не навязчиво, не обидно, и исправит кодом, а не пустыми рассуждениями.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Мало рейтинга, не могу коммент добавить к ответу, где предлагается reduce() заменить на цикл с

```py
number = digits[0]
for d in digits[1:]:
    number = 10 * number + d
```

Такой цикл будет работать только для одиночных цифр.

Comment: Если не хватает рейтинга,  дайте полноценный ответ.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Вам откроются комментарии, когда у вас будет 50 рейтинга. Это не так много и вы сможете, отвечая на вопросы, быстро его достичь. До этого момента, воздержитесь от комментариев в форме ответа. Либо пишите ответ - дополнение